# How to statistic every button click in mfc using message loop mechanics?

Tags: mfc, message-loop

I have a MFC application. I want to statistic every button click, including button ID and time. Can I do it in `CWinApp::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)` or  `CWnd::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)`? And how?

Answer (score 0):

For your own app catching [WM_CHAR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646276(v=vs.85).aspx) should do the job, but if you are looking to catch key strokes for the entire system a hook dll, using [SetWindowsHookEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx), is what you need.

Comment: How will catching WM_CHAR help in counting BM_CLICK notification messages?